# Can you give me two translations into predicate logic that are distinct for the sentence?

Tags: logic

Consider the claim "Nothing cleans like Lysol." It can, I think, be translated in two distinct ways using  two different quantifier expressions of a predicate logic. Can you give me two translations into predicate logic that are distinct in that way. Also can you explain why claims of this sort are seemingly always false. I'm having trouble grasping it but this is what I tried
When you translate both ways you should get something like
~(3x)Cx and (x)~Cx.
both make it seem like there is nothing on this earth that can clean like Lysol which seems quite odd because even Lysol is something and if Lysol cannot clean like Lysol then the statement just seems incorrect altogether..

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA ow yes! i edited it and added my trials.. how about now?

Comment: You are right: Lysol clean as well as Lysol.

Comment: "Nothing cleans like Lysol" is a shorthand for "Nothing cleans like Lysol other than Lysol itself", ~∃x (C(x,l) Λ x ≠ l), where C(x,y) is the "x cleans like y" predicate, and l is a constant for Lysol; x ≠ l can also be expressed as ~(x=l). Can you figure out another way?

Comment: "My name is NoMan." Joke played on the Cyclops by Odysseus. Later on in the story Odysseus pokes out they Cyclops's eye and the Cyclops roars, "NoMan has poked out my eye," and nobody pays attention. https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0136%3Abook%3D9%3Acard%3D360

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a solve your homework problem website.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda this isn't a home work just a problem i found interesting while reading a book don't be bummer man.

Comment: @Assfawkidane lol

Answer (score 3):

Setting aside the issue of representing the sentence in predicate logic for a moment, there are several points to note.

The words 'nothing' or 'nobody' in English are quantifiers, but syntactically they are used in a similar way to a name. So, for example, the sentences "John loves Mary" and "Nobody loves Mary" appear similar in structure, but 'Nobody' is not a name. The latter sentence could be glossed as "there is no person who loves Mary".

Lewis Carroll has fun with this in Alice Through the Looking Glass:

> “Who did you pass on the road?" the King went on, holding out his hand
> to the Messenger for some more hay. "Nobody," said the Messenger.
> "Quite right," said the King; "this young lady saw him too. So of
> course Nobody walks slower than you." "I do my best," the Messenger
> said in a sullen tone. "I'm sure nobody walks much faster than I do!"
> "He can't do that," said the King, "or else he'd have been here
> first.”

So, "Nothing cleans like Lysol" is best understood as "there is no thing that cleans like Lysol cleans", rather than "There is a product called Nothing and it cleans like Lysol cleans". As you point out, Lysol cleans like itself, so this cannot be true without qualification. Formal logic is good at handling seemingly pedantic points about things having to be distinct.

Since Lysol is a product that a person might use, it is also possible to interpret the sentence as "Using nothing cleans in a similar fashion to using Lysol", which we might gloss as "Lysol is so poor at cleaning, you may as well use nothing". While this is a possible interpretation, the sentence looks like an advertising slogan, so we may reasonably suppose this is not what the author had in mind.

In addition, there is an implicature that 'like' here is intended to convey 'as well as'. Strictly speaking, "Nothing cleans like Lysol" could mean that alternatives to Lysol are better, or that some are better and some worse, just none are similar. Again, we would reasonably reject such meanings in an advertising slogan.

Here are some formal translations. No thing that is not Lysol cleans like Lysol:

¬(∃x)[ ¬(x=lysol) ^ CleansLike( x, lysol)   ]

Nothing is a thing that cleans like Lysol:

CleansLike( nothing, lysol )

Using nothing is like using Lysol. This really needs a more expressive logic, but it is perhaps something like:

(∀x)[ ( SimilarTo( ResultOfCleaning( x, 0 ), ResultOfCleaning( x, lysol ) ]

(I’m taking liberties here by using 0 to denote nothing.)

No thing that is not Lysol cleans as well as Lysol:

¬(∃x)[ ¬(x=lysol) ^ CleansAsWell( x, lysol)   ]

Or the last one could be:

¬(∃x)[ CleansBetterThan( x, lysol) ]

Here we don’t need the ¬(x=lysol) condition, since we may assume that CleansBetterThan(x,y) is irreflexive.

Comment: thanks so much for the help.

Comment: "Nothing cleans like Lysol" is best understood (by material implication?) as "there is no thing that cleans like Lysol cleans". Out of curiosity, what leads you to dismiss the implicature "Lysol cleans the best"? Isn't the inference to be drawn about perlocutionary force that the act of persuasion aims for the consumer to purchase Lysol before any others?

Comment: I think the implicature is correct. Given that this is an advertising slogan, we can reject the interpretation that it just means other things are not _like_ Lysol. Rather, other things are not as good as Lysol. The last version of the sentence captures this in the simplest way.